# MySQL Command Line ClientとMySQL Command Line Client - Unicodeどっちが無難？

Tags: mysql

MySQL Command Line ClientとMySQL Command Line Client - Unicodeの違いは文字コード規格のUnicodeの違いでしかないようですが、どちらを使ったほうが無難でしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

以下の MySQL のドキュメントの「Unicode Support on Windows」というセクションに説明があります。

4.5.1.6 mysql Client Tips
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html

MySQL command line client - Unicode で、Windows のコンソールがサポートしている UTF-16LE が使えるようになるということらしいです。

具体的にどういうことかというと、自分が試した限りの話ですが、例えば以下のようなテーブルが MySQL にあるとすると、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ちなみに、最後の行の Title の各文字は以下の通りです。

あ : Shift_JIS にあります
丂 : 0x4E02、BMP には含まれるが Shift_JIS にはありません
 : サロゲートペア
 : サロゲートペア
‍ :  と  を ZeroWidthJoiner (0x200D) で連結

MySQL command line client の場合は以下のようになります。Shift_JIS 以外は認識してくれないようです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

MySQL command line client - Unicode の場合は以下のようになります。  ‍ も where Title like '%〇%' の 〇 としては有効でした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

【追記】

上の説明より以下のように charset を調べた方が分かりやすかったと思います。

Command Line Client

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Command Line Client - Unicode

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

character_set_client: クライアントが送信するステートメントの文字セット

haracter_set_connection: サーバーがステートメントを受信したあと、変換する文字セット

character_set_results: サーバーがクライアントにクエリー結果を返信するときに使用する文字セット

Answer (score 1):

無難という文言に何を期待しているのかわかりませんが

チェックしていませんが、その「 `UNICODE` を使う」の意味が

- Client - Server 間の通信に `UNICODE` を使う
- 操作員（人間） - Client 間の UI に `UNICODE` を使う

で異なるでしょう。

前者ならば事前にエンコーディング設定値を取り交わせばよいだけなので差はないから、こっちとは考えにくい。
後者なら、日本語 Windows のコマンドプロンプトは何も設定しなければ UI に `CP932` を使うので `MySQL Command Line Client - Unicode` だと `CP932` なコンソール上で `UNICODE` を使うことになって文字化けします。

逆に、今後は UI として `UNICODE` (っつか `UTF-8` なり `UTF-16` なり) に移行していくであろうことをにらんで今すぐに `UNICODE` 側を使うほうが将来性はあるかもしれないです。

`UNICODE` にあって `CP932` にない文字（デーヴァナーガリー文字とかタイ文字とか絵文字とか) を使うことが想定されるのであれば `UNICODE` が必須となりますが、コンソールの設定とかフォントの設定とか、環境整備がきっちりできないと実用するのは難しそうです。